# How to eliminate repetition in mips?

Tags: assembly, mips

i have a question regarding the code MIPS below , this supposed to do the hanoi problem + calculating the number of necessary moves.
everything works as how it suppose to do but there's a problem , it repeats the process of changing disque multiple times and it's annoying me to say the least.
I hope smebody helps me regarding this .

```
    .data
    message1:   .asciiz "\n donner le nombre de dsque ( inferieure a 5 svp ): "

    message2:   .asciiz "\nDeplacer le disque de la tour "

    message3:   .asciiz   " Vers la tour "
    
    message4: .asciiz "\n LE nombre de deplacements neccessaires est :: "
    
    space: .asciiz "\n"
    
.text  
  .globl main

main:

    li  $v0, 4          #AFFICHAGE DE MESSAGE1
    la  $a0, message1
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
 
    addi $a1 , $v0 , 0
    
        
    li $t0, 2

    jal Power
    
    
    li $v0, 4       
    la $a0, message4
    syscall
    
    
    move $a0, $t0
    subu $a0 , $a0 , 1
    li $v0, 1       
    syscall
    
    add $a0 , $zero , $zero 
    move $a0 , $v0 
    
    
    
    li $v0 , 4
    la $a0 , space
    syscall
    
    
    
 
   
    
    add $a0, $v0, $zero         #$a0 = va avoir le nombre de disques
    
    addi $a1, $zero, 'A'        #$a1 = poto de source
    addi $a2, $zero, 'B'        #$a2 = poto de destinaton
    addi $a3, $zero,'C'         #$a3 = poto intermidiare
    
    jal hanoi
    


    
    
    li $v0, 10          # pour arreter la fonction
    syscall
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------    
hanoi:        
    
    
    
      # si nombre de disques == 1 ( notre cas de base)
    

    addi $t0, $a0, 0        # $t0 pour temporairement sauvegarder $a0
    addi $t1, $zero, 1
    bne $a0, $t1, sinon
    li $v0, 4           # afichage de message2
    la $a0, message2
    syscall
    li $v0, 11          # afficher A
    move $a0, $a1
    syscall
    li $v0, 4           # affichage de message3
    la $a0, message3
    syscall
    li $v0, 11          # affichage C
    move $a0, $a2
    syscall
    addi $a0, $t0, 0        # pour restaurer  $a0
    jr $ra
    
sinon:
    #grandir la pile


        addi $sp, $sp, -20
    
    
        sw $ra, 16($sp)
        sw $a3, 12($sp)     #sauvegarder $a0 - a3
        sw $a2, 8($sp)      
        sw $a1, 4($sp)      
    sw $a0, 0($sp)

            
        addi $t3, $a3, 0        #PERMUTATION ENTRE 'C' ET 'B'
        addi $a3, $a2, 0        
        addi $a2, $t3, 0        
        addi $a0, $a0, -1       # ( n-1 )           
        
    #l'appel recursve se deroule ici
            
    jal hanoi   
        
    #load off stack
        lw $ra, 16($sp)
        lw $a3, 12($sp)     #charger $a0 - $a3 dans la pil 
        lw $a2, 8($sp)      
        lw $a1, 4($sp)      
        lw $a0, 0($sp)      
   
    #deplacer le disque de source vers disque de distination
        

    addi $t0, $a0, 0        #  sauvegarder temporairement $a0
        addi $t1, $zero, 1
        li $v0, 4           # afficher message2
        la $a0, message2
        syscall
        li $v0, 11          # afficher start_peg
        move $a0, $a1
        syscall
        li $v0, 4           # afficher message3
        la $a0, message3
        syscall
        li $v0, 11          # afficher C
        move $a0, $a2
        syscall
        addi $a0, $t0, 0        # resmessage3re $a0
    
      
        

            addi $t3, $a3, 0        
            addi $a3, $a1, 0        #permutation entre A et C pour un appel prochain dans la recursion
            addi $a1, $t3, 0        
            addi $a0, $a0, -1       # ( n-1 )       
        
            
        jal hanoi   #l'appel recursive   
        
        #load params off stack
            lw $ra, 16($sp)
            
    
        addi $sp, $sp, 20       #faire vider la pile parceque on n'a plus besoin 

    
        add $v0, $zero, $t5
        jr $ra              #equivalant a return0
#--------------------------------

Power:  #faie u, espace dans la pile pour deux elements 
    addi $sp, $sp, -8
    #sauvegarder register $a1 pour un utilisation pochaine
    sw $a1, 4($sp)  
    #sauvegarder l'adresee de retour
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    
    #decrementer n 
    addi $a1, $a1, -1   #$a1 = n-1
    #quand $a1 recoit 0, exit
    beq $a1, $zero, Exit    
    #recursion      
        jal Power
        
        #t1 = 2 * power 2^(n-1)
    mul $t0, $t0, 2     
    
    add $a1 , $0 , $0
Exit:   #restaurer les registres
        lw $a1, 4($sp)
        lw $ra, 0($sp)
        addi $sp, $sp, 8
        
        #retourner l'adresse de registre 
        jr $ra
```

Comment: You need to explain where in the code it changes disks. It's unreasonable to expect people to try to understand your large program without any help. Also explain what happens when you step through the disk-changing code in a debugger. Does a jump instruction jump to the wrong place?

Comment: i'm so sorry for that but i had to include the entire programe because before i added the fonction that calculates (2^n - 1) the code was working just fine it did the expected movements , but when i added the POWER fonction it seems like it repeated output (correct output) multiple times , i don't know even what's the cause for that

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the "POWER" function. Tell us where exactly it does something you didn't expect. It's not clear what the inputs and outputs to the POWER function are.

Comment: Also, look closer at `add $a0, $v0, $zero         #$a0 = va avoir le nombre de disques`. Does $a0 really have the number of disks?

Comment: `#load params off stack` is a comment that says one thing, but the code does something different.

Comment: Your register usage is unusual but that's ok if you're not trying to be standard.  I can't find a flaw in the assembly, so am suspecting that your algorithm is flawed.

Comment: One good approach here is to write the algorithm in C or other HLL to make sure the algorithm works as you intend (most of this assembly is dealing with stack frames & recursion (absent in C), so should only be ~half a dozen lines of C), only then take it to assembly, and if it doesn't work the same in assembly, then can only be due to assembly typo or other low level error, rather than being algorithmic issue; algorithmic issues are much harder to debug in assembly, especially with recursion involved.